# Jquery, Codeigniter 2.1 - How to check if update is succesfull

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

How can I see if the update, after JQuery post, is succesfull?

JQuery code:

```
var code = $('#code'),
     id = $('input[name=id]').val(),
     url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>mali_oglasi/mgl_check_paid';
     code.on('focusout', function(){
        var code_value = $(this).val();
        if(code_value.length < 16 ) {
            code.after('<p>Code is short</p>');
        } else {
            $.post(url, {id : id, code : code_value}, function(){
        });
        }
     });
```

CI controller:

```
function mgl_check_paid()
    {
        $code = $this->input->post('code');
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->mgl->mgl_check_paid($code, $id);
    }
```

CI model:

```
function mgl_check_paid($code, $id){
        $q = $this->db->select('*')->from('ad')->where('id_ad', $id)->where('code', $code)->get();
            $q_r = $q->row();
            if ($q->num_rows() != 0 && $q_r->paid == 0) :
                $data['paid'] = 1;
                $this->db->where('id_ad', $id);
                $this->db->update('ad', $data);
                return TRUE;
            else :
                return FALSE;
            endif;
    }
```

I need to check if update is successful and show appropriate message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI controller:

```
function mgl_check_paid()
{
    $code = $this->input->post('code');
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    // could also return a json or whatever info you want to send back to jquery
    echo ($this->mgl->mgl_check_paid($code, $id)) ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```

Jquery

```
 var code = $('#code'),
 id = $('input[name=id]').val(),
 url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>mali_oglasi/mgl_check_paid';
 code.on('focusout', function(){
    var code_value = $(this).val();
    if(code_value.length < 16 ) {
        code.after('<p>Code is short</p>');
    } else {
        $.post(url, {id : id, code : code_value}, function(data){
           // display the data return here ... simple alert
           //$('.result').html(data); // display result in a div with class='result'
           alert(data)
        });
    }
 });
```

You may also want to read more @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (if you want to do better error checking like failure)

Comment: Cool, nice and simple :). Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, mad props, I <3 CI and jQuery.  Secondly, you need to `echo` in order to return `data` to your jQuery post.

Gimmie 5 to fix something at work and i'll edit this answer with more detail.